# Hide my email by iCloud+ doesn't return email to the textfield after selection

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

I have a register account screen with form. It has some data fields with email and confirm email. When I am taping email field, there is a suggestion for "Hide my email" in the accessory area of keyboard. On tapping "Hide my email" and completing the flow my textfield is not being populated with the selected relay email address.

[image: Register form]
[image: Hide my email button]

What can be the issue?

My text field is setup like this

```
        let view = UITextField()
        view.font = .primary(.regular, size: .body)
        view.textColor = .lblPrimary
        view.tintColor = .lblPrimary
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.textContentType = .emailAddress
        view.keyboardType = .emailAddress
```

I tried putting breakpoint on the delegate methods of textfield. As soon as I press "hide my email". It calls "textFieldDidEndEditing" delegate method and then never autofill the textfield later.
What can be wrong ?